# How do you perform an XOR operation of a unsigned long integer and a character array in C?

Tags: c

These are my two variables with which I want to do an xor operation (in C).

```
unsigned long int z=0xB51A06CD;

unsigned char array[] = {0xF0,0xCC,0xAA,0xF0};

desired output= 0X45D6AC3D
```

I know I cannot do a simple `z ^ array`, because it's a character array and not a single character. Will I have to do XOR of one byte at a time or is there a function for it in C?

I am trying all kinds of crazy things to get it done, but failing miserably all the time. If anyone can help me out with a small code snippet or at least a rough idea, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: No special function, you have to do it one character at a time. Unless you are sure about the endianness.

Answer (score 3):

Cast the `array`, which is treat as a pointer to the first element in an expression like this one, to a long pointer instead of char pointer , and dereference it.

```
unsigned long result = z ^ *(unsigned long *)array;
```

Comment: That's dangerous; you don't know that the byte array is appropriately aligned for `unsigned long`.

Comment: Probably an obvious warning, but when casting make sure that the byte order and endiannessis correct.  If the OP is in control of the array contents it shouldn't be an issue.  If it is coming from an outside source (COMM port, socket, etc...) all bets might be off.

Comment: Plus chars are unicode in C#, so the value you xor will actually be 0x00f000aa00cc00f0

Answer (score 1):

Just make an `unsigned long int` out of your array (warning, it depends on the machine endianness!):

```
unsigned long int z=0xB51A06CD;
unsigned char array[] = {0xF0,0xCC,0xAA,0xF0};

unsigned long int w = 0;
w |= array[0] << 0;
w |= array[1] << 8;
w |= array[2] << 16;
w |= array[3] << 24;

unsigned long output = z ^ w;
```

Comment: It doesn't depend on machine endian-ness, you've just done it the wrong way. The questioner's desired result indicates that `array[1]` should be shifted by 16, not 8, since `0x1A ^ 0xCC == 0xD6`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long int z=0xB51A06CD;

unsigned char array[] = {0xF0,0xCC,0xAA,0xF0};
unsigned long tmp;
memcpy(&tmp, array, sizeof tmp);
... z ^ tmp ...
```

Note that this still makes a number of non-portable assumptions: that `unsigned long` is 4 bytes, and that the system's endianness is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Either my answer or @K-ballo's answer might be more useful, depending on how you want to deal with the endianness issue.  The specific requirements are not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you have to worry about endianness and size of long.  Here's how to make it safe:
1) instead of unsigned long, use uint32_t (from inttypes.h), to be sure you get a 4 byte type.
2) use htonl() as a platform-independent way to ensure you interpret the array as a big-endian value

```
z ^ htonl(*(uint32_t *)array);
```